# How to declare Classic COM Interface IBindCtx in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop, com-interface

I am currently poking around C# and COM interfaces.  COM Documentation in C# is sparse because C# came after COM (perhaps we at SO can fix).  I discovered [the C# compiler can give informative error messages](http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/c-versions-of-com-interfaces.html).  One can read the C# syntax version of the method signatures from the error messages and then add to your class.  This worked for IAdviseSink but does not work for IBindCtx.

I am getting error for the last method `RevokeObjectParam(string a)` the syntax in C++ is `HRESULT RevokeObjectParam( [in] LPOLESTR pszKey );` and `LPOLESTR` is a null terminated 2 byte based string so using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]` should work.  But it doesn't, I get error messages

```
     * Class1.cs(25,14,25,40): error CS0539: 'IBindCtx.RevokeObjectParam' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface
     * Class1.cs(6,18,6,24): error CS0535: 'ComInterfacesInCSharp.Class1' does not implement interface member 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx.RevokeObjectParam(string)'
```

So how do I amend this method signature to fix please?  Full code copyable into Visual Studio is below (create a Class Library project).

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComInterfacesInCSharp
{
    public class Class1 : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx 
    {
        void IBindCtx.RegisterObjectBound(object obj) { }
        void IBindCtx.RevokeObjectBound(object obj) { }
        void IBindCtx.ReleaseBoundObjects() { }
        void IBindCtx.SetBindOptions(ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.BIND_OPTS opts) { }
        void IBindCtx.GetBindOptions(ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.BIND_OPTS opts) { }
        void IBindCtx.GetRunningObjectTable(out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IRunningObjectTable tab) { }
        void IBindCtx.RegisterObjectParam(string s, object obj) { }
        void IBindCtx.GetObjectParam(string s, out object obj) { }
        void IBindCtx.EnumObjectParam(out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumString enumString) { }

        /* Problem here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693771(v=vs.85).aspx
         * C++ Syntax is 
         * HRESULT RevokeObjectParam( [in] LPOLESTR pszKey );
         * LPOLESTR is a null terminated 2 byte based string so UnmanagedType.LPWStr ought to work
         * 
         */
        //void IBindCtx.RevokeObjectParam(string a) { }
        void IBindCtx.RevokeObjectParam([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string a) { }

        /*
         * Compile errors are
         * Class1.cs(25,14,25,40): error CS0539: 'IBindCtx.RevokeObjectParam' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface
         * Class1.cs(6,18,6,24): error CS0535: 'ComInterfacesInCSharp.Class1' does not implement interface member 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx.RevokeObjectParam(string)'
         */
    }
}
```

Incidentally, if you have a web resource detailing these interfaces in C# then that would be marvellous!

Comment: It is not clear what you asking.  That said, the interface method RevokeObjectParam returns an `int`.  See: [IBindCtx](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/ComTypes/ibindctx.cs,83034c257e1bd273)

Comment: @TnTinMn: The link you have given is superb! It answers my question which was what was correct method signature.  Now I have definitively from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the link you have given is superb! It answers my question which was what was correct method signature. Now I have definitively from Microsoft.

While you can find many of the source code definitions from [Microsoft's Reference Source site](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/), it is not your only option for discovering the signature for a method defined in an assembly.

Learn to use [Visual Studio's Object Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf(v=vs.100).aspx).  View Menu->Object Explorer (or press the F2 key).

In your particular case of implementing an interface, you can have Visual Studio auto implement the interface for you.  Right-Click on the interface name ad select "Implement Interface".

[image]